# Issue when converting Carbon::now() toDateTimeString() in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, amazon-web-services, homestead, php-carbon

In my code I have a section like this.

```
->whereDate('published_at', '<=', (Carbon::now())->toDateTimeString())
```

This query worked fine in my development machine(homestead) so I pushed it it to dev server(aws).

But I got an issue saying.

> syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

However I tackled this issue and found the issue. I wanted to change the query like

```
->whereDate('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())
```

Only difference is instead of using `(Carbon::now())->toDateTimeString())`, now I use `Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString())` without the surrounding brackets. Now In both environments my code works.

PHP versions in Homsetead and Aws as follows,

output of `php -v` on Homestead

```
PHP 7.1.0-2+deb.sury.org~xenial+1 (cli) ( NTS )
```

output of `php -v` on aws

```
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Jan 18 2017 19:08:44)
```

I only can think of occurring this issue is due to the difference of php version.

**But it confuses me how removing surrounding brackets made my code work. Appreciate your input on this. Thanks!**

Comment: It's for sure that this happens because of different versions of PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(Carbon::now())->toDateTimeString()` is something you should never need to do. The only time I would use parenthesis like this is if I was newing-up a class.

`Carbon::now()->toDateTimeString()` is the correct way.

That being said, with Laravels query builder you shouldn't need to add `toDateTimeString()` at all.

You should be able to just:

```
->whereDate('published_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for your input. I actually made this change and corrected my query before I posted this issue. My concern is about brackets as the code was working in homestead. It only broke when I pushed it into aws server.

Comment: @Gayan just don't use the brackets in this situation as there isn't any benefit. As I said in my example, for class based situations, I would only use them for something like `(new SomeClass)->someMethod()`.